# ts-node throws ERR_REQUIRE_ESM but "tsc && node" works fine

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm making a very simple Node.js + Express API using Typescript with absolute imports, but for some reason it doesn't work with ts-node. This is my nodemon command:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --transpile-only src/server.ts
```

My package.json doesn't include a "type", and my tsconfig.json has the following configuration:

```
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
```

but when I try to run ts-node using nodemon, I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: [...]\node_modules\axios\index.js
```

All my .ts files are using "import" instead of require.

If I understand this correctly, newer versions of Axios are ESM only, so one option would be to downgrade it. However, if I run "tsc && tsc-alias && node dist/server.js" everything works fine, so why isn't ts-node working?

Comment: ts-node is just bad in my experience... It's a PITA to config and seemingly ignores your tsconfig for no reason... Generally, just a nuisance when I can just `tsc -w` and `nodemon` the output for incremental compilation and running the output whenever it changes. Like, why should you care that `ts-node` saves you 3 characters on the command line if it requires you to add more configuration and flags when you can just `tsc && node`? Sorry for the rant but that's literally how bad it is.